# Excel file generated by openpyxl need repaired when opening

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have a problem when generate excel file as HttpResponse in django using openpyxl=2.3.3.

Example code:

```
        # I just simply read a file and export
        wb = load_workbook('test.xlsx')  # WorkBook object.
        ws = wb.get_active_sheet()
        response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet; charset=utf-8')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="test1.xlsx"'
        response.write(save_virtual_workbook(wb))
```

The excel file can be opened normally by libreOffice. But for Microsoft excel, it shows warning that file need repaired when open.

I tried open broken file by OpenXML SDK and this is the validation result:

[image]

Then I compared the original file and prepare files (broken file is on the left):

[image]

So it seems the structure of  doesn't exists in spreadsheetml/2006/main. Microsoft Excel raise validation warning and just add 'Ignore' to it. Also there are incorrect xfIds:

[image]

I am currently using python 2.7 and openpyxl 2.3.3 for some reason cannot upgrade to 3.0 at the moment. Could you please suggest some work around or some manually config to avoid the warning from Excel.

Comment: There should be no reason why you can't use openpyxl 2.6

Comment: Hi Charlie, thank you for replying.
We have some legacy stuff like from openpyxl.writer.write_only import WriteOnlyCell
In our code which we need to keep version consistent.

Also, I tried openpyxl==2.6 yesterday with a simple excel file. The validation still appear:
The element has unexpected child elements "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main:color"

I will update the excel test file.

Comment: Ok, I cannot upload a sample file in stackoverflow. How I created the file: I just opened blank excel file, then input 'aa' to A1 and saved. Then in python, read and write and the validation appear.

Comment: The validation error is not correct as the order of the child elements is not important there.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem:
the file docProps/core.xml seems to be changed after read and write by openpyxl.

I added a work around by adding pre-module, unzip and store docProps/core.xml.
After process by openpyxl before export, I unzip and overwrite this file with the original one.

It works for me and Excel show no validation error anymore.

Updated: incorrect part from core.xml:

```
<dct:created xmlns:dct="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="dcterms:W3CDTF">2016-06-30T14:08:36Z</dct:created>
<dct:modified xmlns:dct="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="dcterms:W3CDTF">2019-08-28T13:46:19Z</dct:modified>
```

It should be 'dcterms:created' or 'dcterms:modified' instead.

Then I track this '{http://purl.org/dc/terms/}created' it really return dct:created. So might not be openpyxl bug but this dublin core bug.

Comment: I don't think this is relevant.

Comment: Ah, I am not sure but, I tried unzip xlsx file then fixed the dct part only and zip it back, and the excel is good. No warning from M.Excel anymore.